# Parse.com cloud bad request 400

Tags: javascript, cordova, parse-platform

I use Parse.com cloud to manage my database for mobile application. When I save in table user some user with the same username or email it gives me the error:

```
POST https://api.parse.com/1/users 400 (Bad Request)
```

I understood by myself that error appears when the username or email are the same in different users. Is there a method to return the reason of the error like "this mail is already chosen"? Below my code:

```
 saveUser: function() {
        this.utente.save(null, {
            success: function(persona) {
                //console.log("modello salvato nel db");
                var id = persona.get("objectId");
                window.localStorage.setItem('parseId', id);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert("Save error");
                console.log(error);


            }
        });

    },
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you aren't using `response.error(error)` anywhere...

Try

```
saveUser: function() {
    this.utente.save(null, {
        success: function(persona) {
            //console.log("modello salvato nel db");
            var id = persona.get("objectId");
            window.localStorage.setItem('parseId', id);
        },
        error: function(error) {
            response.error(error);
        }
    });
}
```

And then in your native script console.log the error.code and error.message.